# Android how to get resource identifier from external storage

Tags: java, android, resources, environment

I need to get .png image files from external storage located in Downloads folder, with Environment path to /storage/emulated/0/Download/some_image_folder.

I am trying to read files with getResources().getIdentifier() method for External storage, but resource id is not found

```
//For Internal 
int imageId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "raw", getContext().getPackageName());

//For External not working
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + "image_folder_name";
int imageId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", path , getContext().getPackageName());
```

So if I am using "raw" folder for internal storage where images are stored, everything works fine.

When I use path for external folder image id cannot be found, it returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device, and files on the device are not resources. There is no resource identifier for your file, as it is not a resource.